# how to get max of column values in a row in ssrs matrix report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created a SSRS report which shows Hours as column names and dates as row names. Cell values represents the Sales of a specific hour of a specific date.

the table in my report is as follows:

### Date     |Hour 1|Hour 2|Hour 3|max sales|min sales

4/10/2015|   5  |  10  |  15  |    15   |   5
4/11/2015|   30 |  10  |  20  |    30   |   10

I want Green color background in cell with max sales and Red color background in cell with min sales. the required output will be as follows:

### Date     |Hour 1    |Hour 2 |Hour 3   |max sales|min sales

4/10/2015|5(Red)    |  10   |15(Green)|    15   |   5
4/11/2015|30(Green) |10(Red)|  20     |    30   |   10

I have written a custom code for GetColor as follows:

```js
Function GetCellColor(ByVal minValue As Integer,ByVal maxValue As Integer, ByVal currentValue As Integer) As String
    If currentValue = maxValue Then
        return "Green"
    Else If currentValue = minValue Then
        return "Red"
 Else
  return "WhiteSmoke"
    End If
End Function
```

which returns color based on cell value. I can not pass the maxValue, minValue of a row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can answer the following question. But since I have bellow 50 reputation I have no right to answer. This is frustrating. What can I do to answer questions ?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606814/ssrs-parameter-onchange-event

Comment: You can change the color of a textfield this way: Right click on the textfield. In the context menu click `Textfield Properties`. Then goto "Fill" or "Background". Click the Fx Button. There you can add a formula for your background color. To access your custom function use `=code.GetCellColor()` to access your datasets use `Fields!currentValue.Value`. By the way, you could also solve this by using the IIF Function instead of the vb script.

Comment: You should be able to **answer** a question but not **comment**. Were you clicking below the question or in the **Your Answer** section?

Comment: When a Cell is going to be colored I want to calculate max, min sales from the column values of a row and pass to the function GetCellColor @Koryu

Comment: I didn't try using Your Answer section. Just right now I have answered that question. Thanks @Hannover Fist

Comment: There is the [Max-Function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155828(v=sql.100).aspx) to caluclate the max value for a data region.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this the way you are doing it but you'll need to use the same field or expression that you use to populate your **Min** and **Max** columns in your Code call. If you use an expression to calculate it, you would use the same formula.

```
=Code.GetCellColor(Fields!Max_Sales.value, Fields!Min_Sales.value, Fields!YourField.value)
```

As Koryu mentioned, you can accomplish this without using code by putting the logic in the **Expression** for the background color property:

```
=IIf(Fields!YourField.value = Fields!Max_Sales.value, "Green",
 IIf(Fields!YourField.value = Fields!Min_Sales.value, "Red", 
  "WhiteSmoke"))
```

Comment: I can calculate the max_sales and min_sales using query in dataset and follow the above approach. But I want to calculate max_sales and min_sales values from the column values of the matrix. and also pass the calculated max, min values to the function GetCelColor(max,min,current) @Hannover Fist